# How long a search keyword is allowed when using grep

Tags: grep

I'm using a `grep`

The command I'm using

```
grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt
```

I wonder how long a string is allowed for a value of *macthing-keywords*

Because I'll make 10 million letters into *macthing-keywords*

I wonder if this is possible.

Comment: Why don't you try and find out?

Comment: The limiting will be your shell.

Comment: Don't. Create a regex trie (it is the right approach if you use word boundaries or use the patterns inside longer expressions). Or use a different possibly non-regex approach.